# how to resolve favicon.ico error in google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2

I have a very basic jinja template, which works OK in displaying htm, but the log complains about favicon.ico even though I have it in both / and /templates. what did I do wrong?
also, am I getting an error in my css load?

```
import jinja2
import os
import logging
import webapp2

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'])

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

def get(self):
    path = self.request.path
    logging.info('from main %s', path)
    if (path=='/'):
      templa=JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('/templates/index.htm')
    else:
      templa=JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template(path)
    try:
      self.response.write(templa.render({})) 

    except:
      self.response.out.write('Error - unable to find %s' % path)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/.*',MainHandler)],
 debug=True)
```

------ showing only error
INFO     2013-10-07 19:44:53,500 index4.py:44] from main /templates/topics.htm
INFO     2013-10-07 19:44:53,516 dev_appserver.py:3103] "GET /templates/topics.htm HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2013-10-07 19:44:53,532 dev_appserver.py:3103] "GET /static/glike.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2013-10-07 19:44:53,609 index4.py:44] from main /favicon.ico
ERROR    2013-10-07 19:44:53,609 webapp2.py:1552] 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 142: invalid start byte
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in **call**
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in **call**
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in **call**
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\projects\apps\ae-07-grades\index4.py", line 48, in get
    templa=JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template(path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\jinja2\jinja2\environment.py", line 719, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\jinja2\jinja2\environment.py", line 693, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\jinja2\jinja2\loaders.py", line 115, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\jinja2\jinja2\loaders.py", line 169, in get_source
    contents = f.read().decode(self.encoding)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 142: invalid start byte
INFO     2013-10-07 19:44:53,641 dev_appserver.py:3103] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like jinja2 is trying to load `/favicon.ico` as a jinja template, and is choking on it.

The usual way to handle `/favicon.ico` is to declare it as a static file in `app.yaml`.

See [favicon.ico "not found error" in app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887328/favicon-ico-not-found-error-in-app-engine)