# want to display a favicon on Nuxt.js + Google App Engine

Tags: vue.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, nuxt.js

**Premise / What I want to achieve**

I'm deploying a Nuxt.js app in SSR mode on Google App Engine.
At the time, the favicon is no longer displayed, so I want to be able to display it.

```
yarn build + gcloud app deploy
```

By the way, it was displayed without any problem with the following command.

```
yarn dev

yarn build + yarn start
```

**Corresponding source code**

```
export default = {  
  head: {
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon',
      type: 'image/x-icon', href: 'images/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  }
}(nuxt.config.js)
```

```
runtime: nodejs12

instance_class: F2

handlers:
  - url: /_nuxt
    static_dir: .nuxt/dist/client
    secure: always

  - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt))$
    static_files: static/\1
    upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt)$
    secure: always

  - url: /sw.js
    static_files: static/sw.js
    upload: static/sw.js

  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always

  - url: /images/favicon.ico
    static_files: static/images/favicon.ico
    upload: static/images/favicon.ico

  - url: /assets
    static_dir: assets

env_variables:
  HOST: '0.0.0.0'
  PORT: '8080'(app.yaml)
```

I placed the favicon.ico under the static / images directory.

Answer (score 0):

From the command you are running, you do not appear to be declaring the `app.yaml` file when deploying the app.

```sh
yarn build + gcloud app deploy
```

Try:

```sh
gcloud app deploy app.yaml --project [project-id]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I did gcloud app deploy app.yaml --project [project-id] but the result didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into the [App Engine Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/serving-static-files#configuring_your_static_file_handlers) regarding how to set the Favicon.ico

The Vuejs apps are managed as static websites by App Engine as Vue runs on the front-end.

Therefore you would need to configure the app.yaml to use static files.

**app.yaml**:

```
env_variables:
  HOST: "0.0.0.0"
  PORT: "8080"

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: static/favicon.ico
  upload: static/favicon.ico

- url: /sw.js
  static_files: static/sw.js
  upload: static/sw.js

- url: /static
  static_dir: public

- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
```

Please have a look into the following [App Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/serving-static-files#serving_from_your_application) for static files in App Engine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

I changed the code but did not solve it.

Comment: ```
runtime: nodejs12

instance_class: F2

handlers:
  - url: /favicon\.ico
    static_files: favicon.ico
    upload: favicon\.ico

  - url: /sw.js
    static_files: sw.js
    upload: sw.js

  - url: /assets
    static_dir: assets

  - url: /_nuxt
    static_dir: .nuxt/dist/client
    secure: always

  - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt))$
    static_files: static/\1
    upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt)$
    secure: always

  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always

env_variables:
  HOST: '0.0.0.0'
  PORT: '8080'
```

Comment: I did "gcloud app logs tail".

"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /sw.js HTTP/1.1" 404

Comment: I have edited my answer, please have a look at it. Could you please tell if your favicon.ico is located in the static directory? Could you please share your App Engine app structure?

Comment: Please note that the favicon and swj entry should be placed before the entry for the main handler.

Comment: Also could you please share how are you showing your favicon.ico in your vue.js app.

Comment: Sorry for contacting you so late.
The favicon.ico is directly under the static directory.
I have srcDir:'app' in nuxt.config.js set so the static directory is under the app directory.

Comment: handlers:
  - url: /favicon\.ico
    static_files: static/favicon.ico
    upload: static/favicon\.ico

  - url: /sw.js
    static_files: static/sw.js
    upload: static/sw.js

  - url: /sitemap.xml
    static_files: static/sitemap.xml
    upload: static/sitemap\.xml

  - url: /assets
    static_dir: /assets

  - url: /_nuxt
    static_dir: .nuxt/dist/client
    secure: always

  - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt))$
    static_files: static/\1
    upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt)$
    secure: always

  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always

Comment: Since there is a static directory under the app directory, do I need to change things like -url?

Comment: I have a favicon.ico specified in nuxt.config.js.
link: [
      { rel: 'icon',
      type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
       ]

Comment: Hello, could you please edit your post with the modified files, so that it is easier to read what you have modified? I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887328/favicon-ico-not-found-error-in-app-engine) which might help further.