# React app crash loop on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine

I just deployed the frontend of my app to app engine. I created this frontend with create-react-app and it worked perfectly locally.

When I deploy it to App Engine with `gcloud app deploy app.yaml`, I get the following logs which keep on repeating.

I am not sure where the error lies ; the favicon is in the public directory. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: logs]

Comment: Hi @Matthieu, was my answer helpful ?

Comment: Hi @JoseGermanPerezSanchez, I appreciate your help ! Turns out it was actually a proxy error between my backend and frontend. Will write up an answer

Comment: Hey @Matthieu, good to know you found the solution. Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above case, my app wasn't able to locate some files. I used `create-react-app` and found the following documentation [link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) solved my issue.

- This is down to the proxy I used to connect the above frontend to a backend in development in `package.json`
- This proxy doesn't work in production, and is just a convenience to avoid CORS. Deleting it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

`/favicon.ico` is often handled by declaring it as a static file in `app.yaml`.
As a suggestion, you can review this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887328/favicon-ico-not-found-error-in-app-engine) question.

Also, searching for similar situations like yours, it is also recommended to clean your browser cache.